# Simple assignment issue via set/get

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accessor, unityscript, mutators

I'm using Unity 3 and I'm trying to perform a simple assignment of the variable linearLimit>limit within the ConfigurableJoint component. I'm using the code below but I keep getting the error "Cannot modify a return value, try placing it within a variable first". I've used accessors and mutators countless times but I've never had this issue before. Am I doing something wrong?

//My Code

```
ConfigurableJoint cj = gameObject.GetComponent(); cj.connectedBody = objectToGrab;

cj.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
cj.yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
cj.zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;

float newLimit = 1.0f;
cj.linearLimit.limit = newLimit;
```

//Unity's public Accessor/Mutator for that variable

```
public float limit { get {return this.m_Limit; } set {this.m_Limit = value; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to pass a SoftJointLimit

```
SoftJointLimit newLimit= new SoftJointLimit();

newlimit.limit= 1.0f;

cj.linearLimit = newlimit;
```